# A female demon name starting with the letter "S"

Tags: demons, curses

Is there a female demon in christain or pagan mythology who's name starts with the letter "S". In a TV documentary titled "A haunting" on Discovery, I herd her name but have forgotten. I think its "sarah" or "sera" or "seri". I don't remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean a [Succubus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succubus). Wikipedia defines them as:

> a Lilin-demon in female form, or supernatural entity in folklore (traced back to medieval legend) that appears in dreams and takes the form of a woman in order to seduce men, usually through sexual activity. The male counterpart is the incubus.

For example, [this entry](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15674a.htm) in the Catholic Encyclopedia indicates that one of the charges brought about against "witches" was that of "intercourse with incubi and succubi" (where succubi is [the plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/succubi#English) of succubus).

Answer (score 1):

While I was not able to find any female demons that sound like "sarah", there is the Prince of Hell, [*Seir*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demons_in_the_Ars_Goetia#Princes), mentioned in the *Ars Goetia*. The [*Pseudomonarchia Daemonum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomonarchia_Daemonum) also does not list any demons similarly named, so it was either Seir or the - already mentioned - Succubus, though this is more like saying "The angel Seraphim", since Succubus is a collective word, not an actual name.

Comment: Isn't a prince a male, generally?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes, Seir is a male demon, though since Xlam could not remember the name correctly, it is well possible the gender is wrong as well. And Seir just fits so well, I thought I might point it out.